# How to parse this log with DateTime?

Tags: python

my file have this format :

`script_2022-08-12_20-00-39.log`

how can i parse it with

```
while True:

    try:
        print("Parsing")
        time.sleep(1)
        parse_log('script_2022-08-12_20-00-39.log')
```

Date change it sure every day .

Sorry for my bad English .

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your question is, but if it's "how do I extract the timestamp from this string using datetime", then the answer is

```py
from datetime import datetime

s = "script_2022-08-12_20-00-39.log"
dt = datetime.strptime(s, "script_%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S.log")
# dt == datetime.datetime(2022, 8, 12, 20, 0, 39)
```